# Configuring a React-Express App on Heroku to Pull Data in an Ajax Request

Tags: reactjs, express, heroku

I have a React-Express app that pulls data from a MongoDB database on mLab.

On my server.js file, I have the api port set as such:

```
var port = process.env.PORT || 3001;
```

And it listens as such:

```
app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log(`api running on port ${port}`);
});
```

Currently, in my React app, one of the components makes an AJAX call to the database on mLab using the url of "http://localhost:3001/api/data", which works fine and pulls the data I requested.

However, when I deploy the app to Heroku, I'm not sure how to configure the server.js and the url in the React app, so the React app is able to pull the data from the database.

I've conferred with mLab, and there are no issues, and I've conferred with Heroku, and this is beyond the scope of their support.

UPDATE: Is it that the process.env.PORT variable needs to be set or redirected?

Any ideas what I need to do?

Thanks!

Comment: Just use the deployment URL for heroku, i.e. `https://myapp.herokuapp.com`.

Comment: I tried that, and it gave me this error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found). That's why I'm confused.

Comment: So you're also serving up the React app alongside Express? Or are they separate?

Comment: Alongside. Here's the server.js page if it helps: https://github.com/adamewhite/bankruptcy/blob/master/server.js

Comment: I've done this multiple times, and Heroku always sets the PORT env variable when 
your app starts. Then, your app should be able to just query your Heroku URL

Comment: That's exactly what I thought it would do, which is why I'm at such a loss now.

Comment: What if you just did `fetch('/api/someRoute')`? Relative to the current URL?'

Comment: Do you mean something like this: `${this.props.location.pathname}/api`? (This url is passed to the component as part of a react-router switch statement.)

Comment: No, since your Express server is at `/api`, just do `/api/...`. I don't think it'll work, but it's worth a try.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't work. Thanks for your suggestions though -- I really appreciate it.

Comment: Very weird. Maybe try using Postman or something? To be clear, have you deployed to Heroku, and if so doesn't your React app work? Maybe something wonky with the ordering of middleware and routes?

Comment: The app works perfectly fine except for the api requests to mLab. It works fine when running locally, but as soon as I deploy it to Heroku, the api requests break.

Answer (score 0):

If your express app is serving both your bundled react app and your api, you need to make sure that express knows that the /api endpoint needs to be NOT served to the react app.

Not sure what your server code looks like, but this has worked for me:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
      app.get(/^\/(?!api).*/, (req, res) => { // don't serve react app to api routes
        res.sendFile(PATHTOREACTBUNDLE));
      });
};
```

Basically, you want to tell express that, if in production mode (deploy on heroku), serve all endpoints, except the api endpoint (/^/(?!api) to your react bundle.

Comment: Thank you, Aaron, for your stab at this! I included that, and it's still giving me a 404 error when the ajax call attempts to connect with the mLab database. What confuses me is that it works fine locally, but as soon as I push it, I'm not sure the url the ajax calls should be using to access the database. Does that make sense?

Comment: Are you using environment variables for the mlab url? If so be sure to set those in your heroku settings.